# Java inheriting POJO classes -> OpenAPI generator -> openapi.json. Then: openapi.json -> OpenAPI generation of Java client classes -> inheritance lost

Tags: java, inheritance, openapi

To create a report of Financial Balances of Cities (shown at the bottom of the question), I'm using classes that inherits each from the other:

```java
/** Comptes avec montant, montant par habitant, strate, taux voté et taux moyen strate. */
@Schema(description = "Comptes avec total, par habitant, moyenne strate, total réduction votée, réduction par habitant, réduction moyenne strate", 
   allOf = ComptesAvecReductionVotee.class, 
   discriminatorProperty = "typeCompteIndividuel")
public class ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate extends ComptesAvecTauxVote {
   /** Moyenne de strate */
   private Double moyenneStrate;

   /** Taux de la strate */
   private Double tauxStrate;
   [...]
```

with:

```java
/** Comptes avec montant, montant par habitant, taux voté. */
@Schema(description = "Comptes avec total, par habitant, total réduction votée, réduction par habitant, réduction moyenne strate", 
   allOf = ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant.class,
   discriminatorProperty = "typeCompteIndividuel")
public class ComptesAvecTauxVote extends ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant {
   /** Taux voté */
   private Double tauxVote;
   [...]
```

and:

```java
/** Forme de comptes individuels : comptes total ou base, et par habitant. */
@Schema(description = "Forme de comptes individuels : comptes total ou base, et par habitant",
   discriminatorProperty = "typeCompteIndividuel")
public class ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant implements Serializable {
   /** Type de compte Individuel */
   @Schema(description = "Type de compte individuel", required = true)
   private String typeCompteIndividuel = getClass().getSimpleName();

   /** Montant total ou base */
   private Double montant;

   /** Montant par habitant */
   private Double parHabitant;

   /** Libellé de l'analyse apportée par cette ligne de comptes individuels. */
   private String libelleAnalyse;

   /**
    * Renvoyer le type de compte Individuel
    * @return Type de compte Individuel
    */
   public String getTypeCompteIndividuel() {
      return this.typeCompteIndividuel;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le type de compte Individuel
    * @param typeCompteIndividuel Type de compte Individuel
    */
   public void setTypeCompteIndividuel(String typeCompteIndividuel) {
      this.typeCompteIndividuel = typeCompteIndividuel;
   }
   [...]
```

Because an individual accounts of cities report have such repetitive structures, and individual accounts of local authorities, departments or regions also have them, sometimes with average calculations, sometimes not.

These inherited classes make it convenient to do some calculations on the same basis.

Everything is written in *Java*, as you can see. But, when I generate through `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin`, configured like this:

```xml
<configuration> 
   <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl> 
   <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName> 
   <outputDir>target/openapi</outputDir>
</configuration>
```

the `openapi.json` file containing many classes of my application,

and that a further project, being a client of it and written in *Java* too, generates for its use the classes from that `openapi.json`, with `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin` configured this way:

```xml
<configuration>
    <inputSpec>${openapi}</inputSpec>
    <output>target/generated-sources/swagger/java</output>

    <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
    <modelPackage>${client.base.package.name}.model</modelPackage>
    <apiPackage>${client.base.package.name}.api</apiPackage>
    <invokerPackage>${client.base.package.name}.invoker</invokerPackage>
    <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>

    <additionalProperties>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <appVersion>1.0.0</appVersion>
    </additionalProperties>

    <configOptions>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
        <oas3>true</oas3>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

the inheritance of these classes isn't respected. Here's what is generated:

```java
@Schema(
   name = "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee",
   description = "Comptes avec total, par habitant, moyenne strate, total réduction votée, réduction par habitant, réduction moyenne strate"
)
public class ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee extends ComptesAvecReductionVotee {
   @JsonProperty("typeCompteIndividuel")
   private String typeCompteIndividuel;
   @JsonProperty("montant")
   private Double montant;
   @JsonProperty("parHabitant")
   private Double parHabitant;
   @JsonProperty("libelleAnalyse")
   private String libelleAnalyse;
   @JsonProperty("reductionVotee")
   private Double reductionVotee;
   @JsonProperty("moyenneStrate")
   private Double moyenneStrate;
   @JsonProperty("reductionVoteeParHabitant")
   private Double reductionVoteeParHabitant;
   @JsonProperty("reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate")
   private Double reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate;
   [...]
```

```java
@Schema(
   name = "ComptesAvecReductionVotee",
   description = "Comptes avec total, par habitant, total réduction votée, réduction par habitant, réduction moyenne strate"
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
   value = {"typeCompteIndividuel"},
   allowSetters = true
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = Id.NAME,
   include = As.PROPERTY,
   property = "typeCompteIndividuel",
   visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(
   value = ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee.class,
   name = "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee"
)})
public class ComptesAvecReductionVotee extends ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant {
   @JsonProperty("typeCompteIndividuel")
   private String typeCompteIndividuel;
   @JsonProperty("montant")
   private Double montant;
   @JsonProperty("parHabitant")
   private Double parHabitant;
   @JsonProperty("libelleAnalyse")
   private String libelleAnalyse;
   @JsonProperty("reductionVotee")
   private Double reductionVotee;
   [...]
```

```java
@Schema(
   name = "ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant",
   description = "Forme de comptes individuels : comptes total ou base, et par habitant"
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
   value = {"typeCompteIndividuel"},
   allowSetters = true
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = Id.NAME,
   include = As.PROPERTY,
   property = "typeCompteIndividuel",
   visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(
   value = ComptesAvecReductionVotee.class,
   name = "ComptesAvecReductionVotee"
), @Type(
   value = ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee.class,
   name = "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee"
)})
public class ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant {
   @JsonProperty("typeCompteIndividuel")
   private String typeCompteIndividuel;
   @JsonProperty("montant")
   private Double montant;
   @JsonProperty("parHabitant")
   private Double parHabitant;
   @JsonProperty("libelleAnalyse")
   private String libelleAnalyse;
   [...]
```

It does only a part of what it should...

OpenAPI wrote few classes having some `extends`, yes, but subclasses still duplicate the fields `typeCompteIndividuel`, `montant`, `parHabitant`, for example. This client compiles, but it isn't the way I'm looking for, and I'm in the middle of things.

1. How do I define such discriminator in my POJO classes?
   I've attempted it, but it doesn't really work.
2. And... Am I required to?
   Can OpenAPI do that as boilerplate generation, like:

   - using the class name for discriminator on generation from server classes
   - and using it too for client classes?

without I have any change to do in my POJO classes? Because adding a field in each able to inherit is cumbersome.

---

The report that the inherited classes help to create (on the *Java* server):

```
Libellé du budget : Douarnenez
Population légale en vigueur au 1er janvier de l'exercice : 14520   Budget principal seul
Strate : Strate commune : communes de 10 000 à 20 000 hab       Type groupement d'appartenance : appartenant à un groupement fiscalisé (FPU)
Exercice : 2019     N° de département : 29      N° insee de la commune : 29046      N° de région : 53


ANALYSE DES EQUILIBRES FINANCIERS FONDAMENTAUX

En milliers d'Euros Euros par habitant  Moyenne de la strate    OPERATIONS DE FONCTIONNEMENT    Ratios de structure Moyenne de la strate (en %% des produits)


                        OPERATIONS DE FONCTIONNEMENT

     21442        1477        1354  TOTAL DES PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A            en % des produits CAF
     21240        1463        1303      PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT CAF
     12379         853         563          dont : Impôts Locaux                 58,28       43,19
      1418          98         115          Autres impôts et taxes                  nu        8,82
      1794         124         177          Dotation globale de fonctionnement        8,44       13,57

     20000        1377        1213  TOTAL DES CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B             en % des charges CAF
     18156        1250        1107      Charges de fonctionnement CAF
     11226         773         655          dont : Charges de personnel          61,83       59,18
      4493         309         272          achats et charges externes           24,75       24,58
       911          63          24          Charges financières               5,02        2,14
       229          16          33          Contingents                   1,26        2,98
      1024          71          89          Subventions versées               5,64        8,02
      1442          99         141  Résultat comptable = A - B = R


                        OPERATIONS D'INVESTISSEMENT

      7099         489         482  TOTAL DES RESSOURCES D'INVESTISSEMENT = C           en % des ressources
      1800         124          79      dont : Emprunts bancaires et dettes assimilées       25,36       16,33
       526          36          72      Subventions reçues                    7,42       14,84
       450          31          40      Fonds de compensation de la TVA (FCTVA)           6,34        8,28
         0           0           0      Retour de biens affectés, concédés, ...           0,00        0,00

      6481         446         500  TOTAL DES EMPLOIS D'INVESTISSEMENT = D              en % des emplois
      4515         311         376      dont : Dépenses d'équipement                 69,66       75,37
      1926         133          86      Remboursement d'emprunts et dettes assimilées        29,72       17,18
         0           0           1      Charges à répartir                    0,00        0,11
         0           0           0      Immobilisations affectées, concédées, ...         0,00        0,00

      -618         -43          17  Besoin ou capacité de financement résiduel de la section d'investissement = D - C
         0           0           1  + Solde des opérations pour le compte de tiers
      -617         -43          18  Besoin ou capacité de financement de la section d'investissement = E
      2059         142         123  Résultat d'ensemble = R - E


                        AUTOFINANCEMENT                         en % des produits CAF

      3855         266         214  Excédent brut de fonctionnement                  18,15       16,43
      3084         212         196  Capacité d'autofinancement = CAF                 14,52       15,01
      1158          80         110  CAF nette du remboursement en capital des emprunts        5,45        8,43

                        ENDETTEMENT                         en % des produits CAF
     25092        1728         850  Encours total de la dette au 31 décembre N          118,13       65,23
     25092        1728         837  Encours des dettes bancaires et assimilées          118,13       64,27
     25064        1726         828  Encours des dettes bancaires net de l'aide du fonds de soutien pour la sortie des emprunts toxiques     118,00       63,52
      2837         195         108  Annuité de la dette                      13,36        8,28
      1516         104         286  FONDS DE ROULEMENT


                        ELEMENTS DE FISCALITE DIRECTE LOCALE
Les bases imposées et les réductions (exonérations, abattements) accordées sur délibérations
Bases nettes imposées au profit de la commune               Taxe                    Réductions de base accordées sur délibérations
En milliers d'Euros  Euros par habitant     Moyenne de la strate            En milliers d'Euros     Euros par habitant   Moyenne de la strate
     25249        1739        1441  Taxe d'habitation (y compris THLV)                2142         148         116
     23211        1599        1384  Taxe foncière sur les propriétés bâties                  0           0           1
       177          12          11  Taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties              0           0           0
         0           0           0  Taxe additionnelle à la taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties
         0           0           0  Cotisation foncière des entreprises                  0           0           0

Les taux et les produits de la fiscalité directe locale
Produits des impôts locaux            Taxe                              Taux voté (%)   Taux moyen de la strate (%)
      6133         422         240  Taxe d'habitation (y compris THLV)               24,27       16,66
      6135         423         313  Taxe foncière sur les propriétés bâties              26,38       22,58
       116           8           6  Taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties          65,39       53,69
         0           0           0  Taxe additionnelle à la taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties           0,00        0,00
         0           0           0  Cotisation foncière des entreprises               0,00        0,00

Les produits des impôts de répartition
Produits des impôts de répartition      Taxe
         0           0           0  Cotisation sur la valeur ajoutée des entreprises
         0           0           0  Imposition forfaitaire sur les entreprises de réseau
         0           0           0  Taxe sur les surfaces commerciales
```

---

What *OpenAPI* REST service call currently respond, if a client calls it:

```json
{
  "anneeExercice": 2019,
  "population": 14520,
  "siren": "212900468",
  "code": "29046",
  "nom": "Douarnenez",
  "produitsDeFonctionnement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 21441.85,
    "parHabitant": 1476.71,
    "libelleAnalyse": "TOTAL DES PRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT = A\t\t\ten % des produits CAF",
    "moyenneStrate": 1354.49
  },
  "produitsDeFonctionnementCAF": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 21240.31,
    "parHabitant": 1462.83,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tPRODUITS DE FONCTIONNEMENT CAF",
    "moyenneStrate": 1302.89
  },
  "produitsDeFonctionnementCAFImpotsLocaux": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 12378.83,
    "parHabitant": 852.54,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tdont : Impôts Locaux\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 58.28,
    "moyenneStrate": 562.74,
    "ratioStrate": 43.19
  },
  "produitsDeFonctionnementCAFAutresImpotsEtTaxes": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 1417.63,
    "parHabitant": 97.63,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tAutres impôts et taxes\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": null,
    "moyenneStrate": 114.91,
    "ratioStrate": 8.82
  },
  "produitsDeFonctionnementCAFDGF": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 1793.63,
    "parHabitant": 123.53,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tDotation globale de fonctionnement",
    "ratioStructure": 8.44,
    "moyenneStrate": 176.8,
    "ratioStrate": 13.57
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 19999.67,
    "parHabitant": 1377.39,
    "libelleAnalyse": "TOTAL DES CHARGES DE FONCTIONNEMENT = B\t\t\t\ten % des charges CAF",
    "moyenneStrate": 1213.14
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAF": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 18156.46,
    "parHabitant": 1250.44,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tCharges de fonctionnement CAF",
    "moyenneStrate": 1107.32
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFChargesDePersonnel": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 11226.09,
    "parHabitant": 773.15,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tdont : Charges de personnel\t",
    "ratioStructure": 61.83,
    "moyenneStrate": 655.33,
    "ratioStrate": 59.18
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFAchatsEtChargesExternes": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 4493.45,
    "parHabitant": 309.47,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tachats et charges externes\t",
    "ratioStructure": 24.75,
    "moyenneStrate": 272.19,
    "ratioStrate": 24.58
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFChargesFinancieres": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 910.77,
    "parHabitant": 62.73,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tCharges financières\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 5.02,
    "moyenneStrate": 23.73,
    "ratioStrate": 2.14
  },
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFSubventionsVersees": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 1024.37,
    "parHabitant": 70.55,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tSubventions versées\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 5.64,
    "moyenneStrate": 88.79,
    "ratioStrate": 8.02
  },
  "resultatComptable": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 1442.19,
    "parHabitant": 99.32,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Résultat comptable = A - B = R",
    "moyenneStrate": 141.35
  },
  "ressourcesInvestissement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 7099.06,
    "parHabitant": 488.92,
    "libelleAnalyse": "TOTAL DES RESSOURCES D'INVESTISSEMENT = C\t\t\ten % des ressources",
    "moyenneStrate": 482.4
  },
  "ressourcesInvestissementEmpruntsBancairesDettesAssimilees": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 1800,
    "parHabitant": 123.97,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tdont : Emprunts bancaires et dettes assimilées",
    "ratioStructure": 25.36,
    "moyenneStrate": 78.77,
    "ratioStrate": 16.33
  },
  "ressourcesInvestissementSubventionsRecues": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 526.43,
    "parHabitant": 36.26,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tSubventions reçues\t\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 7.42,
    "moyenneStrate": 71.58,
    "ratioStrate": 14.84
  },
  "ressourcesInvestissementFCTVA": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 450.22,
    "parHabitant": 31.01,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tFonds de compensation de la TVA (FCTVA)\t",
    "ratioStructure": 6.34,
    "moyenneStrate": 39.93,
    "ratioStrate": 8.28
  },
  "emploisInvestissement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 6481.48,
    "parHabitant": 446.38,
    "libelleAnalyse": "TOTAL DES EMPLOIS D'INVESTISSEMENT = D\t\t\t\ten % des emplois",
    "moyenneStrate": 499.52
  },
  "emploisInvestissementDepensesEquipement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 4514.68,
    "parHabitant": 310.93,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tdont : Dépenses d'équipement\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 69.66,
    "moyenneStrate": 376.48,
    "ratioStrate": 75.37
  },
  "emploisInvestissementRemboursementEmpruntsDettesAssimilees": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 1926.02,
    "parHabitant": 132.65,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tRemboursement d'emprunts et dettes assimilées",
    "ratioStructure": 29.72,
    "moyenneStrate": 85.8,
    "ratioStrate": 17.18
  },
  "autoFinancementCAF": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 3083.85,
    "parHabitant": 212.39,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Capacité d'autofinancement = CAF\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 14.52,
    "moyenneStrate": 195.58,
    "ratioStrate": 15.01
  },

  "endettementEncoursDetteBancaireNetteSoutienSortieEmpruntsToxiques": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 25064.14,
    "parHabitant": 1726.18,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Encours des dettes bancaires net de l'aide du fonds de soutien pour la sortie des emprunts toxiques",
    "ratioStructure": 118,
    "moyenneStrate": 827.62,
    "ratioStrate": 63.52
  },
  "endettementAnnuiteDette": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 2836.79,
    "parHabitant": 195.37,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Annuité de la dette\t\t\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 13.36,
    "moyenneStrate": 107.83,
    "ratioStrate": 8.28
  },
  "fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeHabitation": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee",
    "montant": 25248.77,
    "parHabitant": 1738.9,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe d'habitation (y compris THLV)\t\t",
    "reductionVotee": 2142.17,
    "moyenneStrate": 1441.29,
    "reductionVoteeParHabitant": 147.53,
    "reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate": 116.45
  },
  "fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeFonciereProprietesBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee",
    "montant": 23211.43,
    "parHabitant": 1598.58,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe foncière sur les propriétés bâties\t\t",
    "reductionVotee": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 1384.36,
    "reductionVoteeParHabitant": 0,
    "reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate": 0.86
  },
  "fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeFonciereProprietesNonBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee",
    "montant": 177.14,
    "parHabitant": 12.2,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties\t",
    "reductionVotee": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 10.59,
    "reductionVoteeParHabitant": 0,
    "reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate": 0.02
  },
  "fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeAdditionnelleFonciereProprietesNonBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe additionnelle à la taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties",
    "moyenneStrate": 0
  },
  "fiscLocalBaseNetteCotisationFonciereEntreprises": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Cotisation foncière des entreprises\t\t",
    "reductionVotee": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0,
    "reductionVoteeParHabitant": 0,
    "reductionVoteeMoyenneStrate": 0
  },
  "impotsLocauxTaxeHabitation": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate",
    "montant": 6133.04,
    "parHabitant": 422.39,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe d'habitation (y compris THLV)\t\t",
    "tauxVote": 24.27,
    "moyenneStrate": 240.18,
    "tauxStrate": 16.66
  },
  "impotsLocauxTaxeFonciereProprietesBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate",
    "montant": 6135.35,
    "parHabitant": 422.54,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe foncière sur les propriétés bâties\t\t",
    "tauxVote": 26.38,
    "moyenneStrate": 312.61,
    "tauxStrate": 22.58
  },
  "impotsLocauxTaxeFonciereProprietesNonBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate",
    "montant": 115.92,
    "parHabitant": 7.98,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties\t",
    "tauxVote": 65.39,
    "moyenneStrate": 5.69,
    "tauxStrate": 53.69
  },
  "impotsLocauxCotisationFonciereEntreprises": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Cotisation foncière des entreprises\t\t",
    "tauxVote": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0,
    "tauxStrate": 0
  },
  "impotsLocauxTaxeAdditionnelleFonciereProprietesNonBaties": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe additionnelle à la taxe foncière sur les propriétés non bâties\t",
    "tauxVote": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0,
    "tauxStrate": 0
  },
  "produitsImpotsRepartitionCotisationValeurAjouteeEntreprises": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Cotisation sur la valeur ajoutée des entreprises",
    "moyenneStrate": 0
  },
  "produitsImpotsRepartitionImpositionForfaitaireEntreprisesReseau": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Imposition forfaitaire sur les entreprises de réseau",
    "moyenneStrate": 0
  },
  "produitsImpotsRepartitionTaxeSurfacesCommerciales": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Taxe sur les surfaces commerciales",
    "moyenneStrate": 0
  },
  "ratiosNiveauxEtStructure": {
    "annulationLogique": false,
    "capaciteDesendettement": 8.136469024109473,
    "depensesReellesFonctionnementSurPopulation": null
  },
  "codeRegion": "53",
  "codeDepartement": "29",
  "typeGroupementAppartenance": "appartenant à un groupement fiscalisé (FPU)",
  "libelleStrateCommune": "communes de 10 000 à 20 000 hab",
  "chargesDeFonctionnementCAFContingents": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 228.89,
    "parHabitant": 15.76,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\t\tContingents\t\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 1.26,
    "moyenneStrate": 33.02,
    "ratioStrate": 2.98
  },
  "ressourcesInvestissementRetourDeBiensAffectesConcedes": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tRetour de biens affectés, concédés, ...\t",
    "ratioStructure": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0,
    "ratioStrate": 0
  },
  "emploisInvestissementChargesARepartir": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tCharges à répartir\t\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0.53,
    "ratioStrate": 0.11
  },
  "emploisInvestissementImmobilisationsAffecteesConcedees": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 0,
    "parHabitant": 0,
    "libelleAnalyse": "\tImmobilisations affectées, concédées, ...",
    "ratioStructure": 0,
    "moyenneStrate": 0,
    "ratioStrate": 0
  },
  "autoFinancementExcedentBrutDeFonctionnement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate",
    "montant": 3855,
    "parHabitant": 265.5,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Excédent brut de fonctionnement\t\t\t",
    "ratioStructure": 18.15,
    "moyenneStrate": 214.1,
    "ratioStrate": 16.43
  },
  "endettementFondsDeRoulement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 1516.15,
    "parHabitant": 104.42,
    "libelleAnalyse": "FONDS DE ROULEMENT",
    "moyenneStrate": 285.78
  },
  "operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementResiduelSectionInvestissement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": -617.58,
    "parHabitant": -42.53,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Besoin ou capacité de financement résiduel de la section d'investissement = D - C",
    "moyenneStrate": 17.12
  },
  "operationsInvestissementSoldeDesOperationsPourCompteDeTiers": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 0.28,
    "parHabitant": 0.02,
    "libelleAnalyse": "+ Solde des opérations pour le compte de tiers",
    "moyenneStrate": 0.86
  },
  "operationsInvestissementBesoinOuCapaciteFinancementSectionInvestissement": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": -617.3,
    "parHabitant": -42.51,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Besoin ou capacité de financement de la section d'investissement = E",
    "moyenneStrate": 17.98
  },
  "operationsInvestissementResultatEnsemble": {
    "typeCompteIndividuel": "ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate",
    "montant": 2059.49,
    "parHabitant": 141.84,
    "libelleAnalyse": "Résultat d'ensemble = R - E",
    "moyenneStrate": 123.37
  },
  "codeCommune": "29046",
  "nomCommune": "Douarnenez",
  "sirenCommune": "212900468",
  "populationCommune": 14520
}
```

(It's the output of a container class, `ComptesIndividuelsCommune`, holding the classes I've described, and starting that way:

```java
public class ComptesIndividuelsCommune {
   @JsonProperty("anneeExercice")
   private Integer anneeExercice;

   @JsonProperty("population")
   private Integer population;

   @JsonProperty("siren")
   private String siren;

   @JsonProperty("code")
   private String code;

   @JsonProperty("nom")
   private String nom;

   @JsonProperty("produitsDeFonctionnement")
   private ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate produitsDeFonctionnement;

   [...]
   @JsonProperty("fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeHabitation")
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeHabitation;

   @JsonProperty("fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeFonciereProprietesBaties")
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeFonciereProprietesBaties;
   @JsonProperty("fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeAdditionnelleFonciereProprietesNonBaties")
   private ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate fiscLocalBaseNetteTaxeAdditionnelleFonciereProprietesNonBaties;

   @JsonProperty("fiscLocalBaseNetteCotisationFonciereEntreprises")
   private ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee fiscLocalBaseNetteCotisationFonciereEntreprises;
   [...])
```